# pytorch nn loading checkpoint and steping scheduler

Tags: python, pytorch

Im trying to load a checkpoint in pytorch neural network and step down the learning rate with scheduler but it's not working and line #1 and line #2 print the same thing. sometimes it gives an error like this  `1.1.0 changed this behavior in a BC-breaking way. If you use the learning rate scheduler (calling scheduler.step()) before the optimizer’s update (calling optimizer.step()), this will skip the first value of the learning rate schedule.` and Im using this code at the end of my training loop in an if statement. if further informations you think is necessary please make a comment. cause I think it's enough right now.

```
print('<<<back to the best>>>')
loaded_checkpoint=torch.load("checkpoint.pth")
model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model_state'])
model.to(device)
model.eval()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optim_state'])

print('lr',optimizer.state_dict()['param_groups'][0]['lr']) #1
losss=.9
scheduler.step(losss)
print('<<<back to the best>>>')
print('lr',optimizer.state_dict()['param_groups'][0]['lr']) #2
```

Comment: Where do you do `optimizer.step()`? The message is telling you that you need to do it before `scheduler.step()`.

Comment: there is a loop before this part (this part is in if statement in the loop at the end of each iteration)  and in  the loop(not this if statement there is just `optimizer.step()` and no `scheduler.step()` so `scheduler.step()` is just in this if statement.